# How to call a "vararg" method with an array of params?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I'm trying to call `String.format()` having a `String` and `Object[]`. How can I do it?

Comment: How exactly are you "trying"? And what is happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply like that:

```
String.format(myString, myArray);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me for other vararg methods in java 1.8.

Answer (score 13):

You should just be able to call

```
String text = String.format(formatString, args);
```

... assuming you want the `args` to be the multiple values. If you need extra wrapping, you have to do that yourself:

```
String text = String.format(formatString, new Object[] { args });
```

Basically, if the argument type already matches the parameter array type, the compiler doesn't do any wrapping.

From the JLS, section [15.12.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#45449):

> If m is being invoked with kn actual argument expressions, or, if m is being invoked with k=n actual argument expressions and the type of the kth argument expression is not assignment compatible with T[], then the argument list (e1, ... , en-1, en, ...ek) is evaluated as if it were written as (e1, ..., en-1, new T[]{en, ..., ek}).

Note the "If" at the start - that's what effectively says that if the argument is already okay, no wrapping is performed.

Answer (score 6):

in short by example:
(***S2*** and ***I2*** are likely the most interesting versions **passing** the **varargs as an `Object[]`**)

```
PrintStream ps    = System.out ;

String[]    sarr  = new String[] { "a" , "b" } ;
Object      os    = sarr ;

int[]       iarr  = new int[]     { 1 , 2 } ;  // cannot be cast to Object[] - see I6 below
Integer[]   ioarr = new Integer[] { 1 , 2 } ;  // can    be cast to Object[] - see I2 below
Object      oi    = iarr ;                     // cannot be cast to Object[] - see I6 below

ps.printf( "%n## Strings:%n%n" ) ;

ps.printf( "S1: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            "a"  , "b" ) ;
ps.printf( "S2: pass as varargs objects:           %s, %s%n" , (Object[]) sarr       ) ;
ps.printf( "S3: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            sarr , "c" ) ;
ps.printf( "S4: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            os   , "c" ) ;
// ps.printf( "S5: MissingFormatArgumentException: %s, %s%n" ,            os   ) ;
// ps.printf( "S6: ClassCastException:             %s, %s%n" , (Object[]) os   ) ;

ps.printf( "%n## int:%n%n" ) ;

ps.printf( "I1: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            1     , 2 ) ;
ps.printf( "I2: pass as varargs objects:           %s, %s%n" , (Object[]) ioarr ) ;
ps.printf( "I3: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            iarr  , 3 ) ;
ps.printf( "I4: pass as single objects:            %s, %s%n" ,            oi    , 3 ) ;
// ps.printf( "I5: MissingFormatArgumentException  %s, %s%n" ,            iarr  ) ;
// ps.printf( "I6: ClassCastException:             %s, %s%n" , (Object[]) oi    ) ;
```

outputs:

```
## Strings:

S1: pass as single objects:                a, b
S2: pass as varargs objects:               a, b
S3: pass as single objects:                [Ljava.lang.String;@ad02649, c
S4: pass as single objects:                [Ljava.lang.String;@ad02649, c

## int:

I1: pass as single objects:                1, 2
I2: pass as varargs objects:               1, 2
I3: pass as single objects:                [I@6781882a, 3
I4: pass as single objects:                [I@6781882a, 3
```